# Performance of 2 vector-matrix dot product

Tags: python, performance, numpy, dot-product

The question is more focused on performance of calculation.

I have 2 vector-matrix. This means that they have a 3 depth dimension for X,Y,Z. Each element of the matrix has to make dot product with the element on the same position of the other matriz.

A simple and non efficient code will be this one:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.uniform(low=-1.0, high=1.0, size=(1000,1000,3))
b = np.random.uniform(low=-1.0, high=1.0, size=(1000,1000,3))
c = np.zeros((1000,1000))
numRow,numCol,numDepth = np.shape(a)

for idRow in range(numRow):
    for idCol in range(numCol):
        # Angle in radians
        c[idRow,idCol] = math.acos(a[idRow,idCol,0]*b[idRow,idCol,0] + a[idRow,idCol,1]*b[idRow,idCol,1] + a[idRow,idCol,2]*b[idRow,idCol,2])
```

However, the numpy functions can speed up the calculations as the following ones, making code much faster:

```
# Angle in radians
d = np.arccos(np.multiply(a[:,:,0],b[:,:,0]) + np.multiply(a[:,:,1],b[:,:,1]) + np.multiply(a[:,:,2],b[:,:,2]))
```

However, I would like to know if there are other sintaxis that improve this one above with maybe other functions, indices,...

First code takes **4.658s** while second takes **0.354s**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), which multiplies and then sums over any axes:

```
np.arccos(np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ij', a, b))
```

The more straightforward way to do what you posted in the question is to use `np.sum`, where you sum along the last axis (`-1`):

```
np.arccos(np.sum(a*b, -1))
```

They all give the same answer but `einsum` is the fastest and `sum` is next:

```
In [36]: timeit np.arccos(np.einsum('ijk,ijk->ij', a, b))
10000 loops, best of 3: 20.4 µs per loop

In [37]: timeit e = np.arccos(np.sum(a*b, -1))
10000 loops, best of 3: 29.8 µs per loop

In [38]: %%timeit
   ....: d = np.arccos(np.multiply(a[:,:,0],b[:,:,0]) +
   ....:               np.multiply(a[:,:,1],b[:,:,1]) +
   ....:               np.multiply(a[:,:,2],b[:,:,2]))
   ....:
10000 loops, best of 3: 34.6 µs per loop
```

Comment: @ askewchan good answer. However I don't see so much difference between 3 options. It is true that einsum gives the best solution also in my case but only a 5% improvement.
Maybe it is because previously I calculate the vectors in this way?
```a[:,:,0] = np.sin(azimA)*np.cos(elevA)
a[:,:,1] = -np.cos(azimA)*np.cos(elevA)
a[:,:,2] = np.sin(elevA)``` from a size=(1000,1000) array?

Comment: Hmm, I reduced the size actually for my timings... probably the differences don't scale that much. You really saved most of your savings going from your loop to multiply solution, but the standard way of doing it is what I showed.

Comment: You can save time in what you pasted in your comment by only calculating `cos` and `sin` once per array: `cosazimA = np.cos(azimA)` etc, since you're calculating the same thing twice. But that shouldn't have any effect on the later calculation.

Comment: @ askewchan good point of view! It is possible to make also cross product with einsum as it is ```c[0] = a[1]*b[2] - a[2]*b[1] ``` ```c[1] = a[2]*b[0] - a[0]*b[2] ``` ```c[2] = a[0]*b[1] - a[1]*b[0] ```

Comment: You can just use `np.cross` for that :) Read the docs --- it can be used for many different shaped arrays as long as there's a 3D vector in them somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The [Pythran](http://pythran.readthedocs.io) compiler can further optimize your original expression by:

- Removing temporary arrays
- Using SIMD instructions
- Using multithreading

As showcased by this example:

```
$ cat cross.py
#pythran export cross(float[][][], float[][][])
import numpy as np
def cross(a,b):
    return np.arccos(np.multiply(a[:, :, 0], b[:, :, 0]) + np.multiply(a[:, :, 1],b[:, :, 1]) + np.multiply(a[:, :, 2], b[:, :, 2]))
$ python -m timeit -s 'import numpy as np; a = np.random.uniform(low=-1.0, high=1.0, size=(1000, 1000, 3)); b = np.random.uniform(low=-1.0, high=1.0, size=(1000, 1000, 3)); c = np.zeros((1000, 1000)); from cross import cross' 'cross(a,b)'
10 loops, best of 3: 35.4 msec per loop
$ pythran cross.py -DUSE_BOOST_SIMD -fopenmp -march=native
$ python -m timeit -s 'import numpy as np; a = np.random.uniform(low=-1.0, high=1.0, size=(1000, 1000, 3)); b = np.random.uniform(low=-1.0, high=1.0, size=(1000, 1000, 3)); c = np.zeros((1000, 1000)); from cross import cross' 'cross(a,b)'
100 loops, best of 3: 11.8 msec per loop
```